# Search bar and search display controller without table view

Tags: ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I was wondering if it was possible to have a search bar and search display controller without having a table view on the same view. If this is possible, I would really appreciate it if you would please respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works just fine without a table view.  The [UISearchDisplayController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UISearchDisplayController/searchResultsDataSource) instance needs a searchResultsDatasource and delegate, which are really UITableView datasource and delegate.

Since these implementations are present in UITableViews, they are often reused as the implementations for the search controller, but that needn't be the case.